# Exception handling code doubt

Tags: java

I am very new to this topic. Please bare with my silly doubts. I have the following code where I get a name from user and if its null sone exception is thrown. But here i m not getting any exception it i enter null. Please help me

```
import java.io.*;
class dbz
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s=null;
        try
        {

           BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           s=br.readLine();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what **is** happening, and what you **expect** to happen?  It's not entirely clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: please include some more information regarding expected vs. actual behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You will never receive null as user input from the console, and it would not trigger a `IOException` regardless.

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as below then you'll see the problem for yourself

```
import java.io.*; 
class dbz 
{ 
  public static void main(String args[])  throws IOException
  { 
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
       System.out.println(br.readLine()); 
   } 
}
```